# Route passing in Sinatra for single page app with REST resources

Tags: sinatra, single-page-application

I'm trying to make a single page website with sinatra in the backend.  I want all GET-requests with preferred accept-header "text/html" to return the same page, BUT all requests that wants json to get json-data.

Example:

A GET call to '/users' with accept set to 'text/html' should return index.html.

A GET call to '/users' with accept set to 'application/json' should return the JSON-data with users.

I have tried using a catch-all method for html and using accept-checks like this:

```
# Generic html giver for angular routing
get //, :provides => 'html' do
  pass unless request.preferred_type.to_str == 'text/html'
  erb :index
end

# Give users as JSON
get '/users', :provides => 'json' do
  pass unless request.preferred_type.to_str == 'application/json'
  '["dummy", "array"]'
end
```

...but it doesn't seem to pass to the second route when preferred_type isn't text/html.

Note: I'm useing the string check on preferred_type, since using request.accept? catches all with browsers giving "*/*" as last accept header.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it seems like the culprit is:

```
:provides => 'json'
```

Without it, the passing works as expected.  I guess it's a bug then.